# Android AccessibilityService does not connect

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm trying to extend AccessibiltyService to intercept Notification Events.
My problem is that my class is created by it never connects to the service.

**This is how my app works:**

- There is a service (StatisticsService) that manages the collection of
  several statistics and which needs also to monitor the Notifications
  Events.
- To do so it creates a StatCollector (a java object) for each
  statistic of interest.
- all StatCollector implement the same interface and, once created they store the StatisticService context.
- one of this StatCollector starts my NotificationService which extends    AccessibilityService.

Following are the relevant classes:

**StatCollector:**

```
public class NotificationCollector implements
        StatCollectorInterface {

    private Context context = null;
    private Intent notificationServiceIntent = null;
    private boolean collectorStarted = false;

    /**Constructor**/
    public NotificationCollector(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        collectorStarted = false;
    }
     @Override
     public void startCollector() {
         if (collectorStarted == true)
         {
            return;
         }
             collectorStarted = true;
             notificationServiceIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationService.class);
             context.startService(notificationServiceIntent);
             }

      @Override
      public void stopCollector() {
        if (collectorStarted == false)
        {
            return;
        }
            collectorStarted = false;
            context.stopService(notificationServiceIntent);
            }
```

**NotificationService:**

```
public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger ("Notification");

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
            logger.trace("onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
            logger.trace("onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**Methods from Accessibility Service**/
    @Override
    protected void onServiceConnected() {
        logger.trace("onServiceConnected");
        AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
        info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
        info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_ALL_MASK;
        info.notificationTimeout = 100;
        setServiceInfo(info);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterrupt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        logger.trace("onAccessibilityEvent");
        if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED) {
            logger.trace("notification: " + event.getText());
        }

    }

}
```

**Manifest.xml:** (relevant components)

```
<service android:name=".StatisticsService"/>

<service android:name=".service.NotificationService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
     </intent-filter>
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
         android:resource="@xml/accessibilityservice" />
</service>

...

<uses-permission android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
```

Note that if I add android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE to NotificationService the app crashes with the following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service my.app.StatisticsService@406657d0 
with Intent { cmp=my.app/.StatisticsService (has extras) }: java.lang.SecurityException: 
Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=my.app/.NotificationService } without permission android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE
```

I believe that the problem is that the System is ignoring my NotificationService class since it doesn't explicitly mention that it has BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE permission. But if I add it to the service in the manifest file the app crashes.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the comment of [Dr.Cyanide](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381157/dr-cyanide) I found out that Accessibility should be enabled for a certain app by the user in the Accessibility menu under settings.

Furthermore, the tag

```
<uses-permission android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"/>
```

is not necessary for pre jelly-bean versions so I've removed it since I'm using ICS.

Now the app works exactly as expected

Comment: I know that apps that use Accessibility settings need to be enabled from the Accessibility options of Android, similar to how new keyboards need to get permission to run. Have you checked there to see if your app has permission? Because the error you're getting sounds like that permission is being denied.

Comment: Didn't I do it already in the manifest file using the uses-permission tag?

Comment: Thanks cyanide. The fact that Accessibility Service should be enabled put me on the right track and I could find a solution. See my edit

Comment: Glad I could help! You might help StackOverflow reduce the unanswered questions list if you wrote the Update as a new question and marked it as accepted. It could also help anyone with a similar question to see that it's been answered from the search page. Just a thought :)